# Have a variable output length in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've written a function which has tolerance as one of its inputs, and I'm wondering how to set the output to have the same number of decimal places as the tolerance? I know that you can use `sprintf` to set a number of decimal points, but I can't work out how to set this to be equal to the same number of decimal points as appears in my tolerance. I want it rounded to a degree of precision specified by `tol`, which is an input. So if I put the tolerance as `0.001`, that's the precision I want it to, and this is what I'm finding complicated to do.

Comment: If you want your answer rounded to a certain (let say `d`) number of digits, you can always end your function with `answer = round(answer*10^d)/(10^d)`.

Comment: From R2014b onwards, you can also simply do `answer = round(answer,d)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`round`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html), it has this functionallity built-in:

```
round(4.235,2)
ans = 
      4.23
```

Comment: With the caveat that this functionality was added to `round` in [R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#R2014b).

Answer (score 0):

To round to the nearest unit of a given tolerance, divide through by that tolerance, round to the nearest integer and multiply the result by the original tolerance:

```
round(x/tol)*tol
```

If you mean to assume that `tol` represents a whole number of decimal places, you can determine that number with `log10`:

```
places = round(-log10(tol));
```

You can use this result directly in `sprintf`:

```
output = sprintf('%.*f', places, x);
```